# Is there's a command for yarn to install a subfolder?

Tags: npm-install, subdirectory, yarnpkg

#### Background:

We are using `yarn` in this project and we don't want to write our `package.json` scripts with a mix of `npm`/`yarn` commands.

I have a root directory which contains a few subfolders.

Each holds a different service.

I want to create a script in the root folder that `npm install` each of the services, one by one.

#### Question:

Do you know what would be the yarn alternative to `npm install <folder>`?

I'm looking for something like this psuedo command: `yarn <folder>`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You could use [--cwd](https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/cwd) there is [a git issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/pull/4174) about this :

```
yarn --cwd "your/path" script
```

You can also use cd :

```
cd "your/path" && yarn script
```

Answer (score 3):

To run `yarn install` on every subdirectory you can do something like:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "install:all": "for D in */; do yarn --cwd \"${D}\"; done"
}
```

where

`install:all` is just the name of the script, you can name it whatever you please

`D` Is the name of the directory at the current iteration

`*/` Specifies where you want to look for subdirectories. `directory/*/` will list all directories inside `directory/` and `directory/*/*/` will list all directories two levels in.

`yarn -cwd` install all dependencies in the given folder

You could also run several commands, for example:

`for D in */; do echo \"Installing stuff on ${D}\" && yarn --cwd \"${D}\"; done`

will print "Installing stuff on your_subfolder/" on every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

To run multiple commands in a single subfolder:

```
cd your/path && yarn && yarn some-script
```